# Does downloaded documents leave traces in LiveCD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

For example I'm runing a live CD of Debian in VMware or VirtualBox. In Storage I have only the the ISO of Debian. After I run Ubuntu I download a *txt file, after I restart the VMware the file will not exist anymore. But will that file leave any traces in the system ?

Answer (score 1):

- **internal**:

  - If you booted a *physical* "Live CD", and did *not* mount a local disk drive: if everything went as one should expect, the computer will be *mostly* untouched. The SMART attributes of a hard disk will change nevertheless (e.g. the spin-up/spin-down counter, so one *could* determine if the system has been used in the meantime).
  - If you booted a "Live CD" *image* in a VM, all requests of the virtual machine were routed through the host operating system. In this case, there will be a lot of local modifications, maybe even residue memory content of the virtual machine in a swap file on the host machine.
- **external**:

  - There most probably *will* be some footprint in the firewall/router or cable modem (some of them log accesses to websites), or
  - in the log files at the internet providers site, and in the DNS server log, and
  - in the remote system you have accessed, obviously.